# Find the closest date in a list 12 months ago from today

Tags: excel, vba, date

I have a  list of Dates in a Column from `K5` to the last value in the K column which will vary.

I would like to find the date that is the closest to 12month ago from today.

Comment: *"Closest to"*. Do you mean, before or after that date, or both? If you need this in VBA then show some code you tried. Also, this can easily be done through a formula.

Comment: Something like vlookup((now()-365),k5:k10000,1) but you can test as I am on a smartphone so I cannot.

Comment: And you just want the date? Not a reference to the row or something like that?

Answer (score 0):

Use the first empty column and write this formula:
=ABS(TODAY()-365-K5)
Then just pull it to the end of the column, and filter the smallest value.